# Can someone help with a few problems with a specific permission setup

Tags: 7, views, users

I'm currently involved in a project which needs a pretty specific permission system that I just cannot figure out how to implement and wonder if anyone could help me.

This project is currently using Drupal 7.8 as a base.

There is a need for Anonymous users to be able view certain content but not other content - this is pretty simple and has been done already. Registered users have more permissions to be able to see more of the content and filter views more - again moderately simple and already implemented.

The main issue is that these registered users can be a part of a company, these companies should only be able to see content related to them with certain 'company admin' users having the ability to view all the content on the site regardless.

This last bit has me completely stumped as I don't want each company to have a company page but rather want 1 site to handle everything and look the same to everyone, but once logged in the content becomes relevant. The content on the site is mostly OpenLayers map data and tables created by Views so whatever solution there is to this has to work with Views and most likely Panels.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks
Adam